# Shellscript to monitor a log file if keyword triggers then execute a command?

Tags: linux, logfiles, shell

Is there a cheap way to monitor a log file like `tail -f log.txt`, then if something like `[error]` appears, execute a command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
tail -fn0 logfile | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "pattern"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
                ... do something ...
        fi
done
```

Comment: oh, one more thing, the `tail -fn0 logfile` seems to be expire since the HTTP server log file are quickly renamed and gzip'ed. The script is still monitor the old file-descriptor I think? Is there a way to auto update file inode or something after a period of time for the `tail` command?

Comment: Just add a --retry to the tail command, or use -F instead of -f. That should do it.

Comment: Also consider `grep -q` to set the return code without displaying the matching lines.

Comment: the issue with this is, that logs like catalina,out (apache) have history, so "finished in" kinda patterns already exist. is there a way only check for future logs ?

Answer (score 16):

I also found that you can use awk to monitor for pattern and perform some action when pattern is found:

```
tail -fn0 logfile | awk '/pattern/ { print | "command" }'
```

This will execute command when pattern is found in the log. Command can be any unix command including shell scripts or anything else.

Comment: I would change -f to -F.

Answer (score 5):

An even more robust approach is [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FILE-CONTENT-TEST). This tool can monitor very many things, but one of them is that it will easily tail one or more logs, match against regex and then trigger a script. This is particularly useful if you have a collection of log files to watch or more than one event to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Better and simple:

```
tail -f log.txt | egrep -m 1 "error"
echo "Found error, do sth."
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.