# Shell Script to monitor a continuously updating file

Tags: shell

How to write a shell script which monitors an continuously updating file  and sends an alert for the occurrence of error (matching pattern) and after the error gets  resolved, the script starts reading the file after the last occurence of error so as no further alerts are sent?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331309/shellscript-to-monitor-a-log-file-if-keyword-triggers-then-execute-a-command

Comment: Or maybe you want [`inotifywait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html).